# DynamoDB mapper update item only if HashKey RangeKey pair is in the table

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to design an update function for my DynamoDB table that only updates the record when the hash key and range key pair is in the DynamoDB table. If the item doesn't exist, I would like to throw a badRequestError. How can I use a DynamoDB expression to achieve this? Can I set both the expectedAttribute to `true` and set the conditional operator to `AND`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DynamoDBMapper` you could use `DynamoDBSaveExpression`

Something like:

```
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expected =
    Map.of("hashKeyAttrName", new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(true),
        "rangeKeyAttrName", new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(true));
DynamoDBSaveExpression expression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
expression.setExpected(expected);
dynamoDBMapper.save(item, expression);
```

If condition is not met `save` will trow a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`

Answer (score 0):

My rep is too low to comment [ccamcmxc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893027/ccamcmxc)'s answer, so I'll just give a new answer.

The additional thing you need is to provide `AttributeValue` for the  `ExpectedAttributeValue` call to make the whole thing work. The complete code sample looks like below.

```
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expected = Map.of(
    "hashKeyAttrName", new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue(hashKey))
        .withExists(true),
    "rangeKeyAttrName", new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue(rangeKey))
        .withExists(true));
DynamoDBSaveExpression expression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
expression.setExpected(expected);
dynamoDBMapper.save(item, expression);
```

To add a little flavor to the recipe, the `save` method has an overload that supports you to also provide `SaveBehavior` as the third parameter which gives you even more control.

An example:

```
dynamoDBMapper.save(item, expression, UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES.config());
```